# Hadoop MapReduce Wordcount python execution error

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera, word-count

I  am trying to execute a python MapReduce wordcount Program

I take it from [writing a Hadoop MapReduce program in python](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/)
just to try to understand how it works but the problem always is Job not successful!

I execute `mapper.py` and `reducer.py` using this library in `Cloudera VM`

```
/usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.12.0.jar
```

execute command:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.12.0.jar
-Dmaperd.reduce, tasks=1
-file wordcount/mapper.py 
-mapper mapper.py -file wordcount/reducer.py
-reducer reducer.py
-input myinput/test.txt
-output output
```

[image]

Comment: It would be in your interest to fix the link so users can reference it to better help you.

Comment: The errors aren't here. Look at the YARN UI

Comment: the problem was on the path  thanks, @cricket_007

Comment: What about the path? Feel free to post your solution below as an answer so others know what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was on the path of files mapper.py and reducer.py must be from the local

but input file must be from hdfs path

first, must test python code in local using

```
cat <input file> | python <path from>/mapper.py | python <path from local>/reducer.py
```

then on hdfs

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.12.0.jar 

-Dmaperd.reduce,tasks=1 -file <path of local>/mapper.py 

-mapper "python <path from local>/mapper.py" 

-file <path from local>/reducer.py -

reducer "python <path of local>/reducer.py" 

-input <path from hdfs>/myinput/test.txt 

-output output
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining this. I was stuck on exact problem and couldn't figure out what went wrong.